# What can I do with the two NioEventLoopGroup of the ServerBootstrap.group method

Tags: netty

So far I just began to read how does Netty works, and tried to understand the examples from the [User guide](https://github.com/netty/netty/wiki/User-guide-for-4.x) in the Netty github.

In the server example, there are two `NioEventLoopGroup` passed into `ServerBootstrap.group` method. The guide just says:

> The first one, often called 'boss', accepts an incoming connection. The second one, often called 'worker', handles the traffic of the accepted connection once the boss accepts the connection and registers the accepted connection to the worker.

But what it makes confusing, it isn't saying much about it. I am very curious about what can I do with the `bossGroup` and `workerGroup` in the real world.

How does Netty work with these two `NioEventLoopGroup`?

Answer (score 0):

The first is handling the accepting of the connections and the second will handle the io of the accepted connections. You can also use the same for both (which is what happens if you just use group(EventLoopGroup)). Many times using the same for both is good enough and so allows you to minimize threads. If you need to accept a lot of connections within a short time frame it may make sense to use two different EventLoopGroups and pay the price of using more threads. As always there is always a trade-off.